# Do the sprites inside a PoT spritesheed need to be PoT aswell?

Tags: libgdx, sprites, spritesheet, texture-atlas

I use *TexturePackerGUI* to create PoT spritesheets. But do the sprites inside the spritesheet need to be PoT aswell? If they need to, do I need to disable trimming? The framework I use is libGDX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, they don't need to be POT.**

This is one of the points of spritesheets existence.

However note, if you plan to use mipmaps, colors might blend on lower mipmap levels. Then try to place similarly colored sprites together, or align to POT bounds, or pad them more.